# show that a linear combination of ind standard normal r.v are standard normal and ind

Tags: probability

> Let $A$ and $B$ be two independent standard normal random variables and let $\lambda$ be a constant. Let the two random variables $C$ and $D$ be defined as follows:
>
> $$C = A \cos(\lambda) + B \sin(\lambda)\\D = -A \sin(\lambda) + B \cos(\lambda)$$
>
> Show that $C$ and $D$ are independent and standard normal.

Now, I know that C would be a normal distribution with mean $0(A) + 0(B)$ and Variance $\sin^2(\lambda) + \cos^2(\lambda) = 1$ and same for D. However, I wanted to derive the cumulative joint distribution:

$$\mathsf P\big(A \cos(\lambda) + B \sin(\lambda) \leq a , -A \sin(\lambda) + B \cos(\lambda) \leq b\big)$$

Any tips for this? thank you,

Answer (score 1):

One can clearly see that $C,D$ are jointly gaussian as they are each linear combinations of independent gaussians and therefore any linear combination of $C,D$ is also gaussian (because it is a linear combination of independent gaussians). Therefore, it suffices to check that $C,D$ are uncorrelated to show they are independent.

By linearity of expectation, we can see both $C,D$ are mean zero. Therefore, $C,D$ are uncorrelated iff $E[CD]=0$. Evaluating $E[CD]$ by plugging in the expressions for $C,D$ in terms of $A,B$ and using the fact that $E[AB]=E[A]E[B] = 0$ and $E[BA]=0$, $E[A^2]=E[B^2]=1$, we see that $E[CD]=0$.

Therefore $C,D$ are independent.

Comment: Thanks Batman! I failed to use the joint gaussian argument